# buffer (not cache) usage growing, find the process using it

Tags: linux, memory, buffer

I've a system where the `buffer` usage is growing over the time.

I trace it while monitoring the memory usage with `dstat` ex:

```
# dstat -t -m
----system---- ------memory-usage-----
     time     | used  buff  cach  free
25-08 16:30:51|12.6G 72.0k 2966M  187M
25-08 16:30:52|12.6G 72.0k 2971M  183M
25-08 16:30:53|12.6G 72.0k 2979M  174M^C
```

(this is an example from my laptop, the system I'm talking about was using hundreds of MB).

Do you know how I could find the process(es) using this kind of memory?

I checked the /proc/xx/status smaps etc, but did not found anything about buffers.

Comment: it's kernel memory, use `slabtop`.

Comment: @IporSircer sorry but it's not true:
<pre>
# slabtop -o | grep "Total Size"
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 607709.44K / 641943.48K (94.7%)
# egrep "Buffers:|Cached:|Slab:" /proc/meminfo 
Buffers:             308 kB
Cached:          2026308 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Slab:             647760 kB
# free -w
              total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:       32515716     2482224    27357544      225376         308     2675640    29245636
Swap:      12578812           0    12578812
</pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some hints from from Robert Love himself answering [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-major-difference-between-the-buffer-cache-and-the-page-cache) and [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Buffers-and-Cached-columns-in-proc-meminfo-output)

As I understand this memory is used only by the kernel, trying to find out which process is using it is pointless.